# Rails 4 and Rails 5 share session in Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have two apps. rails 4.2 and 5.1. Both are looking at the same Redis storage(session). I try to share session between them, but i stuck in the moment:
4.2 version stores and get session in that way: `"get" "fe15cb49282a66d684a70fbd5b80b395"`
5.1 version: `"get" "2::e2dc7633569891230cd0bca57eca3035574042b594c3545e2d1a423852076869"`

So the i can`t synchronize them. I suppose 5.1 encrypts session with Encrypted Rails Secrets(were introduced exactly in 5.1)
just in case i have redis-rails-5.0.2 on 5.1 and redis-rails-4.0.0 on 4.2

Is there any way to share session correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that since 5th rails version session has two IDs: public and private. Private is just an additionally hashed public one. So the solution of that can be overriding session id class(it`s [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb)) As many people says to patch it is not a good idea, but in my case it is an acceptable solution.